# Support for push notifications for Google Directory API OU's and Groups

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-apis-explorer

Currently we are working on creating notification channels and able to successfully subscribe to it and also getting notifications if there are any events w.r.t Users.

As per the document in the push notifications it was mentioned that

> Currently, the Directory API supports notifications for changes to the
>   Users resource.

We also want to know if there is any other way/better approach that supports push notifications for  OU's and Groups also

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation, there is no mechanism implemented to get notifications that are not User-related via the Directory API.

---

However, there is a way to get changes related to your OU's and Groups by getting notifications from the [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/push).

If you watch specifically for events from the application(`applicationName`) "admin" you will receive [administrator activity events](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activity-ref-appendix-a/admin-event-names.html).

These events can be of multiple types, including [`ORG_SETTINGS`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activity-ref-appendix-a/admin-org-events) and [`GROUP_SETTINGS`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activity-ref-appendix-a/admin-groups-events).

Go to the documentation for each event type and check out the possible contents!

---

Also, if you'd like to receive these notifications thru the Directory API, there is a feature request for this already reported [here](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760171).

You can subscribe to this by clicking on the star ☆ next to the Issue number in order to receive updates and to give more priority to the bug.